# Why isn't my UIButton in a UIBarButtonItem not showing in the Nav Bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `UINavigationController` which changes the `UIBarButtonItem` in the top right corner, depending on the state of the app.

When view did load I initialize the buttons I need

```
var editBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
var logoutBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
var showRepositoryBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    editButton = UIButton()
    editButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon pencil"), forState: .Normal)
    editButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
    editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(UserProfileNavigatorController.onEditClick), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    editBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: editButton)

    let logoutButton = UIButton()
    logoutButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon logout"), forState: .Normal)
    logoutButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
    logoutButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(UserProfileNavigatorController.onLogoutClick), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    logoutBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: logoutButton)

    let showRepositoryButton = UIButton()
    logoutButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon logout"), forState: .Normal)
    logoutButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
    logoutButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(UserProfileNavigatorController.onShowRepositoryOnWebClick), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    showRepositoryBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: showRepositoryButton)

    presenter.viewDidLoad()
}
```

And depending on the situation, I change the buttons displayed in this way

```
func showUserProfile() {
    navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([editBarButton, logoutBarButton], animated: false)
    Router.showUserProfileInNavigatorController(self)
}

func showRepository(repository: Repository) {
    navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([showRepositoryBarButton], animated: false)
    Router.showRepository(self, repository: repository)
}
```

Even though this code is actually executed, nothing appears in the top right corner.

Comment: Can you post a bit more code. I.e. viewDid/WillAppear and where you call showUserProfile etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that that code was running in the `UINavigationController`. Instead, it's the `UIViewController` who must show the buttons in the `UINavigationController`.

So just moving the code inside the `UIViewController` is working.

Comment: Well, the showRepositoryButton wasn't showing - that was a bug I pointed out below. Really surprised to not even get a thank you for my long and detailed answer...

Comment: @DavidH Sorry if I seemed to be rude. Your solution was actually not working, though you correctly pointed out a different bug. Thanks for that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are multiple problems with your code. First, note that while UIButton() will return a non-optional, UIImage may return an optional. So you really have no idea now whether you actually have typed the names of your images correctly. I created a simple project using your code above, with no images in it, and duplicated that if the images are nil, that nothing shows.

Then adding images, I only got two images showing. Looking closely at your code, the 3rd image re-defines loginButton but does not set any properties on showRepositoryButton.

Several suggestions:

- us "do { ... }" to create a sub context to avoid unintended variable re-use
- if using a UIButton, use the designated initializer (UIButton(type:...)
- better still, use a UIBarButtonItem(image: ...)
- pay really close attention to optionals, and let forced unwrapping crash at the appropriate time (or use an assert, guard, or precondition)

Without drastically modifying your code, here is what works fine for me:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.title = "Howdie!"

    do {
        let button = UIButton()
        let image = UIImage(named: "02-redo")!
        button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onEditClick), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        editBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    }

    do {
        let button = UIButton()
        let image = UIImage(named: "03-loopback")!
        button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onLogoutClick), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        logoutBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    }

    do {
        let button = UIButton()
        let image = UIImage(named: "04-squiggle")!
        button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onShowRepositoryOnWebClick), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        showRepositoryBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    }

    navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([editBarButton, logoutBarButton, showRepositoryBarButton], animated: false)
}
```